# Printing $PATH variable using desktop shortcut

Tags: shell, desktop-shortcuts

I have created an application shortcut in Ubuntu like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Exec=bash -c 'echo $PATH;$SHELL'
Icon=/home/mani/Desktop/omnetpp-5.0/ide/icon.png
Terminal=true
Name=Sample Application
Categories=Development;Application
```

I saved it with `sampleApp.desktop` name. Double clicking on the shortcut shows me this:

[image]

But, the actual value of $PATH is this:

[image]

My guess is that, double clicking on the shortcut, runs the application in a non-interactive shell and the content of my .bashrc will not be parsed. How can I print the full $PATH using desktop shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to say that you want an (`-i`) interactive shell and it'll load up the extra files which express your shell preferences. So:

`bash -i -c 'echo $PATH; $SHELL -i'`

You could also just conditionally echo the path in your .bashrc or .bash_profile and use the environment to trigger that, something like:

```
if [ "" != "$echopath" ]; then
  echo $PATH
fi
```

Then your shell could just be:

`env echopath=1 bash -i`